# pandas.read_html() hangs/silent fail when called in loop

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I'm trying to gather current cryptocurrency price information from CoinMarketCap.com by using pandas.read_html(). Single (manual) calls of the function work great: Open-High-Low-Close data is automatically pulled into a DataFrame. So I made a simple loop to call this for all 1495 (and counting) cryptocoins, but it never gets past the 10th coin, and often stalls at the 2nd, 3rd or 4th call. I've included a short bit of code that illustrates the problem:

```
import pandas as pd

coin_list = ['bitcoin', 'ethereum', 'ripple', 'bitcoin-cash', 'cardano',
             'stellar', 'neo', 'litecoin', 'eos', 'nem', 'iota', 'dash',
             'monero', 'tron', 'icon', 'ethereum-classic', 'qtum',
             'bitgem', 'vechain', 'lisk', 'populous', 'raiblocks']

d_coins = {}

for c in coin_list:
    print('Getting data for: '+c)
    url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/'+c+'/historical-data/?start=20130428&end=20180129'
    d_coins[c] = pd.read_html(url)[0]
```

The code puts each DataFrame into a dictionary, so I can convert it to a Panel later. Even this short sample has never run to completion, but it never throws an error, just hangs for hours if I let it. If pandas.read_html() failed on the first call or at least threw an error it would be something to go on, but it seems to work a few times before just hanging indefinitely. Any ideas?

python version: 3.6.0

pandas version: 0.22.0

html5lib version: 1.0.1

Comment: Looks like either the server is unreliable or you are being throttled.

Comment: A shot in the dark but try adding a `sleep()` to pause between requests.

Comment: Thanks @BradSolomon, I actually did try adding a 10 second sleep() after every pd.read_html() call. The result was the same: ran fine a few times then stalled.

Answer (score 0):

I know its been a while! but I had the same issue this seems like an answer to tackle this:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'http(s)://...'
arr = pd.read_html(requests.get(url, timeout=10).content)  #  timeout is 10 
seconds
```

[refrence](https://www.codestudyblog.com/sf2002b/0207225850.html)